# Adding some one to test ios app in testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

To add any apple id to testflight, is permission needed or without permission the id can be added

Comment: Can i add any one later on stage to add my ios app or i have to add him at the time of uploading app to testflight ?

Comment: Try it. What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a user to your current build they will receive an invite to TestFlight. Once they accept the invite and download the TestFlight app they will be able to install your beta app.

This will *not* require adding their device to your provisioning profile and rebuilding the app.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot for your responce